# Two PC on the same LAN, communicating the same Server

Tags: nat, transport-protocol

Assume that we have 2 pc on the same LAN,
local IP of pc1: `192.168.1.5`
local IP of pc2: `192.168.1.6`

Now suppose that both pc1 and pc2 wants to connect to a server on the internet,
we all know that the server will receive 2 requests from the same IP which is the public IP (let us say it is `216.33.23.5`,
because `192.168.1.5` and `192.168.1.6` are private, and for that, we have port numbers.

So the server will receive 2 combinations of (`IP, source port number`);

let us say they are : (`216.33.23.5, 3455`) and (`216.33.23.5, 4666`)

Now the question is, what will guarantee that pc1 and pc2 will not use the same source port number, then the server will get confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: the NAT router.

The NAT router needs to keep track of its translations, so it'll use distinct L4 port numbers for different connections. For source NAT, a NAT router doesn't normally re-use the client's source port but takes one from its own pool and translates that as well (NAPT).

Answer (score 0):

No it will not use same source port.  Beacuse natting algorithm is designed in such a way different source ports are generated randomly and will allocate as source ports while internal pc or servers are  communicating for internet access . Internal ip will souce natted with isp public ip in this process source port is allocated by layer3 devices  and  this souce Port  can seen in nat table   ..

`Generally souce Port is randomly generated by router or firewall to keep track of connection or session established for both inbound and outbound traffic . Source port is visible in NAT table`